# Best way to keep a DataGridView up to date in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to add a filter textbox to an application so that when a user types text into it, as they type it, the DataGridView will automatically trim down what's being viewed.

Right now DataGridView is bound to a List with my User Objects.

I was in the process of just using LINQ to create a separate List of User objects and then just re update the DataGridView by doing the whole dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredList but is that the best way to go about this?  I feel like I'm doing it the bad way.

Comment: you could also track after each key press and only update after inactivity of some threshold timespan, that will avoid rebind after each character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably similar to what I'd go with. Alternatively you could iterate the list and remove any objects no longer matching which will probably be much more memory-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Your "filteredList" should be a bindingList just so you create a direct interaction between the list and the grid (modifying the grid will modify the list without you having to do any more step).